# Is there a way to draw networkX graphs with colored nodes (optionally) surrounded by a differently colored ring?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I would like to draw geometric graphs that have colored nodes that can additionally have colored rings around each node.

If possible I would even like to make the surrounding color rings optional for each node.

How is it possible to (optionally) add a colored ring around different nodes in a graph?

To draw RGGs I rely on [this](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_random_geometric_graph.html) with small modifications. There you can also add colors to the node itself. The implementation uses matplotlib to do the task.

Comment: I would like is not a question!!! Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: That is, why the Question is in the title itself. The question itself is pretty concrete. I've added a possible wrong path to show you what my general path is just to respond to the comment. This path doesn't improve the question or help anyone. Basically there is a solution but without the rings in the documentation of NX. To add the rings there would be some modifications necessary to the nx.draw_networkx_nodes that I've been not able to make. So I was hoping, that some implementation/git repo etc. already exists that solves it in their own way.

Comment: You can set the argument `edgecolors` in the `draw_networkx_nodes` to whatever color you want to get rings around the nodes. See doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a simple workaround for this:

Draw the nodes twice and then manipulate the zorder of the PathCollection such that the smaller nodes are in front:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.gnp_random_graph(10, 0.5)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

node_size = 50
ring_size = 100 + node_size

edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, alpha=0.4)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(
    G,
    pos,
    node_size=node_size,
    node_color='red',
)

rings = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(
    G,
    pos,
    node_size=ring_size,
    node_color='green',
)

nodes.set_zorder(2)
rings.set_zorder(1)

plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Caveat, if you want to change the alpha value of the nodes this does not work very well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is a great attempt! Didn't even come to my mind that there is such a simple way!